# Android default min sdk not working

Tags: java, android, gradle, telegram, android-min-sdk

I'm newbie and i'm compiling an android source (Telegram App), my problem is that the `build.gradle` file contains **4** minSdkVersion's and i can't run my application on lower than sdk 23.

and of course my default min sdk is set to 14. I don't know why it doesn't work and i can't run it on lower than 23.

My `build.gradle` file is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'



}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig.applicationId = "org.telegram.plusmess"


    sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['./jni/']

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "jni/Android.mk"
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    signingConfigs {
//        debug {
//            storeFile file("config/release.keystore")
//            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
//            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
//            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
//            v2SigningEnabled false
//        }
//
//        release {
//            storeFile file("config/release.keystore")
//            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
//            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
//            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
//            v2SigningEnabled false
//        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

        }

        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        foss {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false

            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    defaultConfig.versionCode = 957

    sourceSets.debug {
        manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    sourceSets.release {
        manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    sourceSets.foss {
        manifest.srcFile 'config/foss/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    productFlavors {
        x86 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }
            versionCode = 2
        }
        armv7 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
            }
            versionCode = 1
        }
        x86_SDK23 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }
            sourceSets.debug {
                manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
            }
            sourceSets.release {
                manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
            }
            minSdkVersion 23
            versionCode = 4
        }
        armv7_SDK23 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
            }
            sourceSets.debug {
                manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
            }
            sourceSets.release {
                manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
            }
            minSdkVersion 23
            versionCode = 3
        }
        fat {
            sourceSets.debug {
                manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
            }
            sourceSets.release {
                manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
            }
            versionCode = 5
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def abiVersion = variant.productFlavors.get(0).versionCode
        variant.mergedFlavor.versionCode = defaultConfig.versionCode * 10 + abiVersion
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionName "3.18.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk", "APP_PLATFORM:=android-14"
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please provide the gradle error that appeared when you trying to build app

Comment: Why do you have `compile.exclude module: 'support-v4'` in there? Have you tried if removing that fixes your problem?

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim No possible error bro, I just can't run it under 23 sdk versions.

Comment: @NickShvelidze The main source had this line, do you suggest to remove it ? The main build file is this: https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/build.gradle

Comment: Try if it works.

Comment: Post the `adb logcat` output from the device you can't run it on.

Answer (score 0):

Search for minSdkVersion 23 and change it to 14.

Please check your Android manifest

I found at

```
x86_SDK23 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }
            sourceSets.debug {
                manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
            }
            sourceSets.release {
                manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
            }
            >>> [minSdkVersion 23]
            versionCode = 4
        }
        armv7_SDK23 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
            }
            sourceSets.debug {
                manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
            }
            sourceSets.release {
                manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
            }
            >>> [minSdkVersion 23]
            versionCode = 3
        }
```

Comment: dude it's not gonna work :D i've done it before but it gave me error.